# document.readyState == "complete" far earlier in IE10+ than Chrome or FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, extjs

I have an application built on ExtJS framework, after logging in, initially a 'head.js' file is loaded, where the first thing it appends to the body of the document is a "Loading..." overlay.

In order to get rid of this overlay after the content has loaded, I added an 'onreadystatechange' listener to the document. For some reason, when the listener is added in IE, the documents readyState is already 'complete', whereas at the same point in FF and Chrome the readyState is still set to 'interactive', and it is triggers properly.

Why is IE setting the readyState to 'complete' so much earlier than Chrome and FF? Is there something better to be listening for that would work on all three browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for but you can remove loading overlay within [Ext.app.Application.init()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.app.Application.html#method-init) method.

> A template method that is called when your application boots. It is called before the Ext.app.Application's launch function is executed so gives a hook point to run any code before your Viewport is created.

I remove my loading overlay like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    ...
    init: function ()
    {
        // Remove loading overlay
        Ext.query('body')[0].innerHTML = '';
    }
    ...
});
```